# Database schema for twitter API json response

Tags: sql, postgresql, twitter, database-design

I want to create a SQL database for storing the response from Twitter API. I need to store all the fields from the json response (https://jsonblob.com/7c497932-271f-11e9-8347-857d471bdc64).

The problem with the JSON response is that the number of fields can change from one tweet to another. I am fairly new to database design and twitter API. 
How do I break down the API data into multiple tables to store data in a normalized manner?

Is of storing the root fields of JSON response as columns of a Postgres table and storing nested JSON data as JSONB type of Postgres database a good option?

Comment: To get a specific answer here, you will need to provide details as to (A) the structure and content of the particular JSON (your linked page is not helpful), and (B) an explantation of your intent and goals. As currently written, I am voting to close as unclear.

Comment: This kind of question is probably better asked on the sister site, http://DBA.StackExchange.com/. You will still need to rewrite for details, as I commented above.

Comment: The link in question contains an example structure of data I need to store in the database. Its represents a tweet and contains metadata of the tweet as well. My goal is to store tweets like this in the database without any data loss and be able to query it later.

Comment: When asking strangers for professional assistance without compensation, you should make it very very easy to do so.

Comment: Sorry if I am too vague. The JSON response from API is complicated, and I am not asking anyone to create a schema for me- just want to understand what is the best approach to break down such JSON data to a relational database.

Comment: That complication is why you should include a prose description of the entities involved to give us a rough idea of the hierarchy of data involved, along with a brief description of what you intend to accomplish with the various parts. This is the very info we need to be able to recommend using the `jsonb` type in Postgres versus normalizing tables.